# c-namespace and type conversion

Tags: java, spring

I have a class with a constructor with 4 Integer args. It is configured in spring xml like so:

```
<bean id="mySearchService" class="app.service.MySearchService"
    c:maxConnectionsPerHost="${maxConnectionsPerHost}"
    c:maxTotalConnections="${maxTotalConnections}"
    c:connectionTimeout="${connectionTimeout}"
    c:soTimeout="${soTimeout}" />
```

My properties file has:

```
maxConnectionsPerHost=50
maxTotalConnections=50
connectionTimeout=500
soTimeout=100
```

But I get the following error:

> Error creating bean with name 'mySearchService' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type [java.lang.Integer]: Ambiguous constructor argument types - did you specify the correct bean references as constructor arguments?

This works if I use `<constructor-arg value="..." />` so I'm wondering if the c-namespace does not to type conversions in the same way as constructor-arg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is the reason:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-ctor-arguments-resolution

All the arguments are of the same type, and probably the parameter names are not available at runtime (no debug info). I can either provide indexes OR use the `@ConstructorProperties` annotation to make the names visible.

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html) mentions that:

> The p-namespace is not as flexible as the standard XML format. For example, the format for declaring property references clashes with properties that end in `Ref`, whereas the standard XML format does not.

and that:

> The `c:` namespace uses the same conventions as the `p:` one (trailing `-ref` for bean references) for setting the constructor arguments by their names.

From this, I infer — although the documentation never seems to say so explicitly — that you actually need to write:

```
<bean id="mySearchService" class="app.service.MySearchService"
    c:max-connections-per-host="${maxConnectionsPerHost}"
    c:max-total-connections="${maxTotalConnections}"
    c:connection-timeout="${connectionTimeout}"
    c:so-timeout="${soTimeout}" />
```

using hyphenated attribute-names rather than camel-case.

Comment: the p namespace uses camel case names with -ref when the value is a bean reference not a value. So I don't think dashes in names makes sense. The camel case names I used are exact matching to the construct or names.

Comment: @Kevin: If that were so, then how could the `-ref` clash with properties that end in `Ref` (as mentioned in the first snippet that I quoted)? What I'm saying is, if the constructor arguments are named e.g. `maxConnectionsPerHost`, then I think the attributes need to be named e.g. `c:max-connections-per-host`. (It's strange, I know, but otherwise the statement in the documentation doesn't really make sense.)

Comment: I don't know how to answer that except to say that I've been using p-namespace forever. And the behavior is that names match the setters names exactly (e.g. camel case), with the exception that values are distinguished from references by the additional suffix "-ref".